# assembly external procedure error

Tags: assembly, procedure

I have this problem: I have this EXTERNAL procedure:

```
low PROC 
print space             ; macro for print
print text              ; macro for print
MOV ax, number
MOV BX, 10
MOV DX, 0000H
MOV CX, 0000H
jump1:  MOV DX, 0000H
        div BX
        PUSH DX
        INC CX
        CMP AX, 0
        JNE jump1 
jump2:  POP DX
        ADD DX, 30H 
        MOV AH, 02H
        INT 21H
        LOOP jump2
ret
endp
```

In program I have in CODE include low.asm and CALL low This line mov ax, number gives error: Forward reference needs override . Can you help me?

Comment: You're not showing it, but obviously "number" has not yet been defined. That is why the compiler is giving you the error. Single pass compilers need symbols to be defined at lower line numbers than they're referenced, otherwise you'll get a "error - forward reference"

Answer (score 0):

Number is not defined. The error is correct. Perhaps you are missing an EQU directive.